# Minecraft won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.9.cool/1.7.9.cool.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'

This is the Error it keeps on giving me. I'm trying to install Single Player Commands

Comment: The latest SPC release was for Minecraft 1.6.2, make sure your running that version or it wont work.

Answer (score 3):

To properly answer you question the latest Single Player Commands release was for version `1.6.2`, and it looks like you are running the latest version, `1.7.9`.

You should create a new profile in the Minecraft launcher and make it download `1.6.2`. Then you should be able to install SPC as you normally would (making sure to use the 1.6.2 profile).

You can download Single Player Commands [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-162-single-player-commands-v49-official-download-spc-noclip/).